masstransit saga state machine with dynamodb: unable to locate property for key attribute
i have created a saga state machine and im trying to store the sagaState in a dynamoDb table. The configuration in startup.cs looks like this:
services.AddMassTransit(x =>
        {
            x.AddSagaRepository<SagaState>()
                .DynamoDbRepository(r =>
                {
                    r.ContextFactory(provider => provider.GetRequiredService<IDynamoDBContext>());
                    r.TableName = "saga-state-machines";
                });

            x.AddSagaStateMachine<OrderStateMachine, SagaState>();
            x.UsingAmazonSqs((context, cfg) =>
            {
                cfg.Host(new ConfigurationHostSettings()
                {
                    Credentials = credentials,
                    Region = RegionEndpoint.EUWest1,
                    Scope = "OrderStateMachineEvents",
                    AmazonSqsConfig = new AmazonSQSConfig()
                    {
                    }
                });

                // Specify the SQS queue to listen to
                cfg.ReceiveEndpoint("state-machine-events", e =>
                {
                    e.ConfigureSaga<SagaState>(context);
                });
            });

        });

The saga state model looks like this:
[DynamoDBTable("saga-state-machines")]
public class SagaState : SagaStateMachineInstance, ISagaVersion
{

    public Guid CorrelationId { get; set; }

    [DynamoDBHashKey("OperationId")]
    public string OperationId { get; set; }

    public string OperationType { get; set; }
    public int Version { get; set; } 

    public string CurrentState { get; set; }

After i publish my first event, i get the following error:
"message":"R-FAULT amazonsqs://eu-west-1/OrderStateMachineEvents/saga-state-machines f0e50000-bdf5-489e-0f2f-08dcee113ed8 \"MyService.StateMachines.Orders.Events.OrderStartedEvent\" \"MyService.Models.Db.SagaState\"(00:00:00.7789645)","level":"Error""exception":"System.InvalidOperationException: Unable to locate property for key attribute OperationId\r\n   at Amazon.DynamoDBv2.DataModel.ItemStorageConfigCache.Validate(Boolean value, String messageFormat, Object[] args)\r\n   at Amazon.DynamoDBv2.DataModel.ItemStorageConfigCache.GetProperty(ItemStorageConfig config, String attributeName, Boolean optional)\r\n   at Amazon.DynamoDBv2.DataModel.ItemStorageConfigCache.PopulateConfigFromTable(ItemStorageConfig config, Table table)\r\n   at Amazon.DynamoDBv2.DataModel.ItemStorageConfigCache.CreateStorageConfig(Type baseType, String actualTableName, DynamoDBFlatConfig flatConfig)\r\n   at Amazon.DynamoDBv2.DataModel.ItemStorageConfigCache.GetConfig(Type type, DynamoDBFlatConfig flatConfig, Boolean conversionOnly)\r\n   at Amazon.DynamoDBv2.DataModel.DynamoDBContext.LoadHelperAsync[T](Object hashKey, Object rangeKey, DynamoDBOperationConfig operationConfig, CancellationToken cancellationToken)\r\n   at Amazon.DynamoDBv2.DataModel.DynamoDBContext.LoadAsync[T](Object hashKey, Object rangeKey, DynamoDBOperationConfig operationConfig, CancellationToken cancellationToken)\r\n   at MassTransit.DynamoDbIntegration.Saga.DynamoDbDatabaseContext`1.Load(Guid correlationId) in /_/src/Persistence/MassTransit.DynamoDbIntegration/DynamoDbIntegration/Saga/DynamoDbDatabaseContext.cs:line 38\r\n   at MassTransit.DynamoDbIntegration.Saga.DynamoDbSagaRepositoryContext`2.Load(Guid correlationId)\r\n   at MassTransit.Middleware.SendSagaPipe`2.Send(SagaRepositoryContext`2 context)\r\n   at MassTransit.DynamoDbIntegration.Saga.DynamoDbSagaRepositoryContextFactory`1.Send[T](ConsumeContext`1 context, IPipe`1 next) in /_/src/Persistence/MassTransit.DynamoDbIntegration/DynamoDbIntegration/Saga/DynamoDbSagaRepositoryContextFactory.cs:line 70\r\n   at MassTransit.DependencyInjection.DependencyInjectionSagaRepositoryContextFactory`1.Send[T](ConsumeContext`1 context, Func`3 send) in /_/src/MassTransit/DependencyInjection/DependencyInjection/DependencyInjectionSagaRepositoryContextFactory.cs:line 87\r\n   at MassTransit.DependencyInjection.DependencyInjectionSagaRepositoryContextFactory`1.Send[T](ConsumeContext`1 context, Func`3 send) in /_/src/MassTransit/DependencyInjection/DependencyInjection/DependencyInjectionSagaRepositoryContextFactory.cs:line 96\r\n   at MassTransit.Middleware.CorrelatedSagaFilter`2.Send(ConsumeContext`1 context, IPipe`1 next) in /_/src/MassTransit/Middleware/CorrelatedSagaFilter.cs:line 45"

im using the following nuget packages:
Masstransit version: 8.2.6-develop.2019
Masstransit.DynamoDb: 8.2.5
Masstransit.AmazonSQS: 8.2.5
As you can see we clearly have the property "OperationId" in SagaState model, however its still saying that its unable to find the property, what am i missing here? It works when i choose InMemoryRepository.
